# partially periodic function and fourier series representation

Tags: signal-processing, fourier

I am thinking about this for a while but I could not reach a conclusion. If I have a periodic signal let's say a square wave but it is only non-zero for t<100 and t>-100. the function is periodic in this range and outside of this range it is 0. Now I wonder if I can take fourier series representation of this signal and wonder if this FS representation is equivalent to FT of the signal in time domain within that range. Or should I take FT of the signal instead dealing with FS representation. The problem is FT will be challenging to apply to this signal and FS representation is much more friendly to use. Can you enlighten me pls?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a periodic signal overall.

Comment: @Andy aka partially

Comment: "partially periodic" means not periodic, @EEstudent. That answers your question.

Comment: It's not very challenging. Hint: you can represent your "windowed" signal as product of one periodic signal and one aperiodic signal, and suddenly things become pretty easy.

Comment: @Marcus Müller thanks a lot I understood what you say good day